# What are the collision domain reducing devices?

Tags: network

What are the collision domain reducing devices?
if collision reduce how it advantage to network?

Comment: A Switch reduces a collision domains to one domain per port.

Comment: only switches can reduce collision domain???

Comment: routers can't reduce collision domain?

Comment: Yeah routers can also reduce collision domains.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "_collision domain reducing_". Looking at it one way, switches _reduce the size_ of collision domains because they _increase the number_ of collision domains, but looking at it the other way, hubs _reduce the number_ of collision domains because they _increase the size_ of collision domains.

Comment: wouldn't it be more accurate to say switches increase Collision domains, since it makes a collision domain for every port connected?

Comment: Smells like homework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A collision is the moment when two or more frames from two or more different devices are in the network at the same time. Collisions are a feature of networks, as ethernet, that were designed to share the same media (**collision domain**) with a contention-based access method.

When a collision happens, the frames become unintelligible, so the devices that sent the frames have to retry later and other devices in the network have to wait until the collision dissapears to try to use the network.

Having a few collisions is not a problem. However, if 50% of the frames in a network suffer collisions, your network will be **slow**, and a slow network can produce higher layer problems as application disconnections, errors, etc.

As more devices are connected to a network the chance of having collisions increases, so the best way to reduce collisions is to **segment** the common media. This segmentation is achieved with switches. Each switch port is a "collision domain", it means that collisions happening in a port are not reproduced in the other ports of the switch.

When your devices are connected to an ethernet hub and device `A` sends a frame to device `B`, all the other devices **see** the frame and are unable to use the network until that frame ends.

When your devices are connected to an ethernet switch and device `A` sends a frame to device `B`, the frames go from port `A` to port `B` and the other ports **don't see** the frame so they see the network free and can use it. It means that multiple **conversations** can be achieved and that collisions happening in one port are isolated to that port.

Comment: I'd say the second sentence of this otherwise good answer seems a little off to me. I would say Token Ring networks share the same media but do not have collisions. So it's more like collisions are a feature of network *protocols* (such as Ethernet) that allow on-demand access to a shared medium. Token Ring only allows access to the medium when the node that wants to send has the token. It's basically a time slot system. You might add that routers separate collision domains and differ from switches in that routers separate broadcast domains also, unlike switches.

Comment: The term of art that describes why Ethernet can have collisions is that it uses a *contention-based* access method, while Token Ring uses a *channel* access method (AKA "deterministic"). So the access method is the aspect of a protocol that determines whether there can be collisions or not on it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox edited !!!

Comment: I might find some word other than segment, because I would tend to think of that as a feature of hubs.

Answer (score 4):

In networks with a shared medium, a *collision domain* encompasses the nodes connected to it. In each collision domain, only a single node may be transmitting at any given time.

If two nodes start transmitting at the same time (due to a signal's propagation delay, this isn't noticeable immediately) the data is garbled, so they need to cease transmission and follow the protocol before trying again. Usually, there will be some random delay before that, so the network bandwidth isn't utilized in this time. Bandwidth is wasted for the time before the collision detection (the unsuccessful, partial transmission) plus the jamming time (to make sure each node has detected the collision) plus the necessary delay (to make a repeated collision less likely).

The effect can be reduced by separating larger collision domains into smaller ones or by getting rid of collisions completely. A network device capable of *buffering* a packet/frame enables separation of the source's collision domain from that of the destination - this can be a switch, a bridge, or a router. This reduction in collision domain size decreases the likelihood of collisions and therefore can potentially increase network throughput.

When both sides of a link are capable of buffering, an appropriate link can even be used for transmitting in both directions simultaneously. This is called full duplex and it removes the collision domain completely. This is the common mode of fully switched Ethernet operation today. Wi-fi on the other hand uses a inherently half-duplex medium and cannot use full duplex (at least not currently).

Comment: So we could define the collision domain as the area of ​​the network where collisions can happen, along with the nodes it affects?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Collions can *happen* in adjacent collisions domains (independently), but they don't *propagate* beyond their very own domain.

Answer (score 0):

Switch, is the answer if you're taking something like the "Basic Networking" course at Motorola.